# php clicking on users name to display profile

Tags: php, html, mysql, href

So i have this code to display all the users in my database and to access them. That works fine but is there any way to get where it says click here just to display a variable in this case the leader name(aka user name)?

```
    <?php


require_once "config.php";
$sql = "SELECT id , leader_name, nation_name, power FROM nation_info";
$result = $link->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $nationList = [];
   $userid = $row['id'];

   echo ' <a href="viewnation.php?id=' . $userid . '">click here</a> '; // the click here on this line
   // echo '<a class="viewProfile" href="viewnation.php?id=' . $userid . '"><button>View Profile</button></a>'; old method of viewing profile
   echo "  Nation Name: " . $row["nation_name"]. "  Leader Name " . $row["leader_name"]. " Power " . $row["power"];
   
   echo "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$link->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about this? Just printing the name in place of click here?

```
<?php


require_once "config.php";
$sql = "SELECT id , leader_name, nation_name, power FROM nation_info";
$result = $link->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $nationList = [];
   $userid = $row['id'];

   echo ' <a href="viewnation.php?id=' . $userid . '">' . $row["leader_name"] . '</a> '; // the click here on this line
   // echo '<a class="viewProfile" href="viewnation.php?id=' . $userid . '"><button>View Profile</button></a>'; old method of viewing profile
   echo "  Nation Name: " . $row["nation_name"]. "  Leader Name " . $row["leader_name"]. " Power " . $row["power"];
   
   echo "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$link->close();
?>
```